# How to initialize checkbox from hashmap (Angular 2)

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox, ngfor

How can we initialize and manipulate a check box value?  I've looked at quite a number of examples, but haven't been able to get any to work.

I'm trying to present a `N x M` table where the rows represent tasks, and the columns students.  The idea is that checking one of the check-boxes in the table assigns a task to a student.

There is a typescript hash map which contains the value of all the `checkboxes`;

```
assigned : { [key:string]:boolean; } = {};
```

the hash key is:

```
var key = a.TaskId + '_' + a.StudentId;
```

The table is generated with a nested ngFor:

```
<tr *ngFor="let t of tasks">

  <td>Task Name for task... {{t.taskId}}&nbsp; &nbsp;</td>
  <td *ngFor="let s of students">

    <input type="checkbox" name=#{{t.TaskId}}_{{s.StudentId}} change="onAssignmentChange(t,s)" [checked]="cbValue(t, s)">

  </td>
</tr>
```

the `cbValue(t, s)` is below:

```
cbValue(taskItem, studentItem) {
   var key =  taskItem.TaskId + '_' +studentItem.StudentId;
   return this.assigned[key];
}
```

This doesn't work, all the checkboxes in the table come up unchecked, no matter what the values in the hash.

I've also tried:

```
    <input type="checkbox"  change="onAssignmentChange(t,s)" [checked]="cbValue(t, s)">

    <input type="checkbox"  change="onAssignmentChange(t,s)" [(ngModel)]={{t.TaskId}}+'_'+{{s.StudentId}} >

    <input type="checkbox"  change="onAssignmentChange(t,s)" [(ngModel)]="assigned[t.TaskId"+'_'+"s.StudentId"]>
```

none of which works.

I seem to be quite in the dark here; `onAssignmentChange` doesn't get triggered either, there are no Errors in console.

Also,

```
...  name=#{{t.TaskId}}_{{s.StudentId}}  ...
```

is this supposed to be a local target or something?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly trivial as we're just going to bind straight to the `assigned` object, since we're using JavaScript's bracket property accessor we also get a free dynamic instantiation of the property through the template (dirty, maybe, but powerful). Additionally, wherever you're processing this later assume that a missing value is false:

**template**

```
<tr *ngFor="let t of tasks">

        <td>Task Name for task... {{t.taskName}}&nbsp; &nbsp;</td>
        <td *ngFor="let s of students">

          <input type="checkbox" name="{{t.taskId}}_{{s.studentId}}" [(ngModel)]="assigned[t.taskId + '_' + s.studentId]">
        </td>
      </tr>
```

Here's a plunker to demonstrate: http://plnkr.co/edit/9RorhJnv42cCJanWb80L?p=preview

Comment: Works like a champ.  Thanks so much; especially for the plunkr.  How does one know when to use the {{}} and when not to?

Comment: There's a primer on it in template syntax, IIRC: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#binding-syntax

The `[]` and `{{}}` are analogous and mark from data to view, `()` is view to data.